# Image processing - How to stack one channel images to create a 2 channel array

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy, image-processing

i have two datasets of images, one with 900 samples and another with other 900 samples. If i take just one image of each dataset and convert them to array they are of shape (1, 128, 118), after the images are read in grayscale mode.

How could i stack these two arrays to be (2, 128, 118)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
img1 = cv2.imread(...)
img2 = cv2.imread(...)
np.stack([img1,img2],axis=0)
```

Comment: Thank you!! It was in fact very simple, but i didn't know how to do this :)